# <div> formatting breaks when css Left is out of view?

Tags: css, html, css-position

Running this JS Fiddle shows my `<div>` formatted correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/MRpj2/1/

It is a container that will act as an `absolute` positioned label. The problem is when you change the `left` property of the `label` CSS class to something high enough (1000px for example) to move the `<div>` out of view. When you do this, you'll have to scroll right to see the `<div>`, but the text is now below the div?

Is there a way around this? Everything I've tried has had no effect.

Comment: If you give `position:relative` to `.label` it works. Is it necessary you want absolute positioned label?

Comment: There is something subtle going on here with the computed width of `.label` when the element is positioned outside of the parent block.  It would be good to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

on the `.label`.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/aqAvr/)

---

**Edit**

As mentioned in the comments. This solely doesn't work in Firefox. So a solution to fix this is to use

```
display: inline-block;
```

instead of floating elements but still together with `white-space: nowrap;`. Check the new demo:

[Second try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/AJUCC/)

Comment: He sets the withs of the div to the width he needs that the text fits in (because of the 'width=auto') but doesnt add the space of the image div.

Comment: @lhan16 I replaced the `float` with display set to `inline-block` and now it's working fine in Firefox too. Could you use this markup? [New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AJUCC/)

Comment: This works for me! Thanks again. Just out of curiosity, could you explain why `vertical-align: top` is now required for my `label-text` CSS class? At first I left it as `middle` but that obviously throws it off.

Comment: @lhan16 I asked the exact same question about the alignment before here: [Where is this gap/margin coming from?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11711070/1456376). The comment under [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11711141/1456376) briefly explains why.

Comment: ahh, that kind of makes sense to me :) Thanks again!